# Rails 4: how to use form_for (has_many :through with extra attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, nested-form-for

I have a Store model, Product model, and a StoreProduct model to form a many-to-many relationship between stores and products.

The StoreProduct model, on top of store_id and product_id, has an attribute price:float.

I'm struggling to figure out how I can design a form to create a new product given the store. Is it better off making a form for a new StoreProduct object? What is the conventional way of doing this?

**store.rb**

---

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :store_products
  has_many :products, through: :store_products
end
```

**product.rb**

---

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :price, on: :create

  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
  has_many :store_products
  has_many :stores, through: :store_products
end
```

**store_product.rb**

---

```
class StoreProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :product
end
```